# Why do some functions in the Linux kernel work differently for string variables and string literals?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

In Ubuntu 16.04 kernel version 4.4, the loadable kernel module has the following behavior:

(Use string literal)

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h> 
#include <linux/mount.h>
#include <linux/path.h>
#include <linux/namei.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>

static int __init myinit(void)
{
    char *path_name = "~/microsoft.gpg";
    struct path path;

    printk("Module Init\n");

    if (kern_path(path_name, LOOKUP_FOLLOW, &path) < 0)
    {
        printk("kern_path fail\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printk("kern_path success\n");
    return 0;
}


static void __exit myexit(void)
{
    printk("Module Exit\n");
    return;
}

module_init(myinit); 
module_exit(myexit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

The result of dmesg is

> Module Init
>
> kern_path success

(Use string variable)

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h> 
#include <linux/mount.h>
#include <linux/path.h>
#include <linux/namei.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <asm/segment.h>

#define MAX_PATH_LEN 256

static char path_name[MAX_PATH_LEN];

static struct proc_dir_entry *proc_file;

static int myopen(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
    printk("Module Open\n");
    return 0;
}

static ssize_t mywrite(struct file *file, const char __user *user_buffer, size_t count, loff_t *ppos)
{
    struct path path;
    ssize_t bytes = count < (MAX_PATH_LEN - (*ppos)) ? count : (MAX_PATH_LEN - (*ppos));

    if (copy_from_user(path_name, user_buffer, bytes))
        return -EFAULT;

    path_name[bytes] = '\0';

    printk("Module Write\n");

    if (kern_path(path_name, LOOKUP_FOLLOW, &path) < 0)
    {
        printk("kern_path fail\n");
        (*ppos) += bytes;
        return bytes;
    }
    printk("kern_path success\n");

    (*ppos) += bytes;
    return bytes;
}

static const struct file_operations fops = 
{
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = myopen,
    .write = mywrite,
};

static int __init myinit(void)
{
    printk("Module Init\n");
    proc_file = proc_create("mymodule", 0644, NULL, &fops);
    return 0;
}


static void __exit myexit(void)
{
    printk("Module Exit\n");
    remove_proc_entry("mymodule", NULL);
    return;
}

module_init(myinit); 
module_exit(myexit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Commands entered in the shell are

> echo ~/microsoft.gpg > /proc/mymodule

The result of dmesg is

> Module Init
>
> Module Open
>
> Module Write
>
> kern_path fail

I did not have a similar problem when writing user application code, but I am really embarrassed because there is a problem with the kernel module.

Why did the problem appear in the second code? How do I fix it?

---

**Answer completed**

Comment: What is `ppos`, and why does it count in the length of the string?

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto It is a pointer to a "long offset type" object that indicates the file position the user is accessing.

Comment: Well, as soon as the string is null-terminated properly (I see now) and `ppos` *might* be OK, there is an only *possible* reason remaining - bad input. The `~` sign might be replaced with another user's home path. Just try to say simply `echo ~/microsoft.gpg` without writing it. And you'll see. I suggest then trying to use double quote marks: `echo "~/microsoft.gpg" > /proc/mymodule`. I hope it helps.

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto And since `user_buffer` is not initialized, you need to add '\0' to the end of the string using a `count` indicating the length of the input.

Comment: What does "file position" to do with file path and name?

Comment: @BronislavElizavetin Unfortunately, Even if I put double quotes and even change "~" to "/ root", the results do not seem to change. The first code works fine and the second code does not seem to work properly even if I try other files.

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto "file position" does not affect path and name. However, if you do not increment "file position" in the read operation of file_operations, the module loops indefinitely.

Comment: OK, so indeed `ppos` may be the reason. You simply adopt this method (`write`) for filling in a path name, not for writing to a file or accessing some real device. And `ppos` may be irrelevant here. You can either try to simply set `bytes = MIN(count, MAX_PATH_LEN);` or, if you decide to preserve existing `count` with `fpos`, at least try to insert a debug printout after null-termination. Just `printk()` that `path_name` and see what it actually contains.

Comment: Why do you need a path name, if you already have a `struct file *` (that is an opened file)?

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto I just want to get file system name of target file using proc module. Without modifying the kernel source code.

Comment: According to `linux/fs.h` on github `struct file` has a `struct path f_path;` member...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto But using filp_open to get `struct file` structure, it also failed. And sys_open is not exposed for module in kernel version 4.4.

Comment: The first argument is `struct file *file`, do not need anything to do to get it...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto the prototype of filp_open is `struct file *filp_open(const char *filename, int flags, umode_t mode)` and I used it like `filp = filp_open(path_name, O_RDONLY, 0);`(`struct file *filp`). [See](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.4/source/fs/open.c#L984)

Comment: Er, i was referring to your `mywrite()` function' first argument....

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto Oh, is that what you mean? Well, that argument is indicate /proc/mymodule. `struct file_operations` is standard interface of file operation, include socket, device driver, etc. That argument is not related to user_buffer. Loadable Kernel Module can use `file_operations ` interface by creating directories and files under / proc and accessing them in the shell.

Comment: `echo` command appends **newline symbol** at the end of the string. Because of that `path_name` in the second example is not the same as in the first one. You can easily detect difference with `strcmp(path_name, "~/microsoft.gpg")`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Wow, that's your real genius! There was such a characteristic in the echo command!

Comment: @Tsyvarev Please write your answer exactly as you wrote it in the comment. I will adopt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mainly used for write into a "kernel file", `echo` command **appends newline symbol** at the end of the string (this is explicitly mentioned in the [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/echo) for `echo`).

Kernel module can easily process this case by discarding the last input symbol if it is newline:

```
if(path_name[bytes - 1] == '\n')
    path_name[bytes - 1] = '\0';
```

Comment: By the way it worth to mention that kernfs followed by its users (sysfs, configfs) and `kstrto*()` family of functions are *\n*-aware.

Answer (score 0):

In comments, @Tsyvarev gave me the correct answer. The string I pass to echo contains a newline character. I put the -n option and removed it.

Thanks, @Tsyvarev!